# Can't figure out why application is redirecting to login page

Tags: asp.net, authentication

I've inherited an ASP.NET application that contains a login screen. When you first start up, or you haven't done anything for a while, it comes up. It turns out we don't need this extra layer of security, and I'm trying to remove it. I thought I removed the code that was doing the redirecting, but it's still going to the login page, even though I've told the app to use default.aspx as the start page, and ensured that default.aspx contains no code that should trigger the redirect (it's using a master page, but the master page also contains nothing that should be redirecting). Where else might it be redirecting to the login page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem. Even though I thought I had all the redirect code removed, there was still some buried in a user control on the default page. Removing that allowed me to bypass the login screen. So, I can't mark any of the responses as the answer, but I gave them all up votes as they were all good answers.

Answer (score 3):

Look for `<authentication>` sections (should be under `<location>` sections) in your web config and delete them

Comment: It was set to mode="Windows". I deleted it, and also tried setting it to None, but it still directs me to the login page.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like it could be forms authentication in effect.

In the web.config file change the authentication mode value to `none` and see if that makes a difference.

```
<authentication mode="none" />
```

Comment: Would that disable the membership APIs? cause he may be using them

Comment: A quick google says it would but the question is about identifying the cause for the redirect.

Comment: It was set to mode="Windows". I deleted it, and also tried setting it to None, but it still directs me to the login page.